# How to have WPF Grid columns width="*" but also have a dynamic minimum width so content doesn't get cropped

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, columndefinition

I have a 3 columns in wpf grid which needs to be proportional

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Yellow"></Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow">
    </Border>
        <Border  Grid.Column="1" Background="Green">
            <Label Content="This is the Green Cell"></Label>
        </Border>
</Grid>
```

The Result is

[image]

The issue is The text in green column is cropped. I can solve the issue by setting MinWidth = "150". But, the green column content will be dynamic, so I can't use value of 150. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want: The `Label` is how horizontally aligned inside its border, so it sizes naturally to whatever it wants to be instead of stretching to its parent. I gave it a semi-transparent background so you can see which portion of its parent it actually occupies.

Then we bind Column 1's `MinWidth` to the `ActualWidth` of the `Label`. Column 1 can go as wide as it likes, but it can't get any narrower than the `Label`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition 
            Width="2*" 
            MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=FixedContent}" 
            />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Yellow" />
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow" />
    <Border  Grid.Column="1" Background="Green">
        <Label 
            x:Name="FixedContent"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="This is the Green Cell" 
            Background="#882266aa"
            />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This works, however there's an issue. When i increase width of the window by dragging with mouse, the min width of green column also increases and as a result if I shrink the window again, the green area doesn't shrink to original min width. This is frustrating wpf doesn't have something inbuilt to handle this like in web application

Comment: @Emzi You left out `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` (or RIght or Center) on the content within the green cell. It must be explicitly Left, Right, or Center to prevent what you're describing.

Comment: @Emzi The Border in column 1 must size proportionally to the grid, but the content *within* that border must be auto-sized, not stretched. If your layout can't work with that requirement, you'll have to do something painful in codebehind.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to achieve expected result using HorizontalAlingment = "Left" which I missed out. Also I guess, I could use width for 1 and 3rd column to be "Auto". Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know why the same thing doesn't work with telerik gridViewColumn, any suggestion?

Comment: I don't have the Telerik controls so I can't test anything with them, and their GridViewColumn is a very different control from the WPF Grid, but if you show me your actual XAML I might hazard a guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap the text, use `TextBlock` instead of Label. Label does not support Text Wrapping.

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Green">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is the Green CellThis is the Green CellThis is the Green CellThis is the Green Cell"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: thanks, but my content won't be text in real life and wrapping won't help. Assume, it has to be a single line. Thanks.

Comment: Then you may need to define the 2nd column width as Auto.

Comment: Well, if I do so I won't be able to expand the green column width.

Comment: Sounds contradictory: it has to take up as much space as possible, but there is no constraint to the other two columns. I would suggest to use databinding and converter, to calculate the width of the 2nd column from the actual width of the content of each column.